# How to serially execute a sequence of instructions using TypeScript and RxJs?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have Array, where the class Instruction has a execute() function that returns an Observable. The execute function will perform an asynchronous task and when it is finished it will call myObserver.complete() which should trigger the next instruction in the list to have its execute() function called. I am not sure how to do this.

I am implementing all of this so I am open to any suggestions including changing the way I have set up my Instruction class. The main goal is I need to run the code in each Instructions asynchronous execute method sequentially. When Instruction is done executing, move on to the next one in the list until everything has been executed.

Currently I do this through recursion where I pass in the list of instructions and then index of the instruction I am currently working on. When finished I increment the index by 1 and call itself again. While that works, there has to be a better way, but I have yet to come up with one. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood well, you could try something like :

```
Rx.Observable.from(yourArray).concatMap(function executeInstruction(item){
  return item.execute(...)
  })
```

Does that correspond to your use case? This assumes that your `execute` function is on each item. `concatMap` will subscribe to each of the observable returned by `executeInstruction` and will subscribe to the next observable corresponding to the next item only when the previous observable has completed. Documentation [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/concatmap.md)

UPDATE: The Typescript way:

```
Observable.from(instructions, (instruction) => {
    return instruction;
}).concatMap((instruction) => {
    return instruction.execute();
});
```

Comment: That looks like it would work for my use case, but I am not sure how to do this with TypeScript. I tried: Observable.from(instructions).concatMap((instruction: Instruction) => {
           return instruction.execute();
        }); That complains: "Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target"

Comment: Ah, there is a fromArray. Trying this out now.

Comment: Well, I can't help with `typescript` but the error message is pretty clear. Check the signature of your call target and the type of the items you provide, it is that simple really... For debugging question on SO, it is advised to provide a sample code reproducing the error. About `fromArray` it is in Rxjs 4, I suppose it is there too for Rxjs 5 but don't take my word for it. Check the documentation

Comment: It looks like I am using rxjs 5.0.0-beta.2. Looking that the docs "fromArray" is deprecated and it says that I should use from instead. The problem with that is I get the error I mentioned in my previous comment even though the docs clearly state that I should be able to pass in an array. You are right about it being better to add sample code. I am using ionic, angular2 and ionic2 and I am not sure how to setup a sample with the same scenario, so I apologize for that.

Comment: SUCCESS! The only way I could get TypeScript to stop complaining about using the from(instructions).concatMap(...) was to add an additional parameter. Here is what worked: Observable.from(instructions, (instruction) => {return instruction;}).concatMap((instruction) => {return instruction.execute();}); This was definitely the way to handle it. Thanks for your help!